# Java: need to know LinkNode constructor and supporting functions

Tags: java, linked-list

I have started looking into LinkedList problems in Java. I have come across LinkNode which has confused me. I found the problem solution below at leetcode: https://leetcode.com/problems/odd-even-linked-list/discuss/78079/Simple-O(N)-time-O(1)-space-Java-solution.
I would like to know more about `LinkNode`. Also, what kind of supporting functions are required to execute the function below?

```
public class Solution {
public ListNode oddEvenList(ListNode head) {
    if (head != null) {
    
        ListNode odd = head, even = head.next, evenHead = even; 
    
        while (even != null && even.next != null) {
            odd.next = odd.next.next; 
            even.next = even.next.next; 
            odd = odd.next;
            even = even.next;
        }
        odd.next = evenHead; 
    }
    return head;
}}
```

Comment: What exactly you want to know about ListNode ? This is how it does look like as mentioned in the question : struct ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode *next;
 *     ListNode() : val(0), next(nullptr) {}
 *     ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(nullptr) {}
 *     ListNode(int x, ListNode *next) : val(x), next(next) {}
 * };

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's already defined by LeetCode in their template, you don't have to code that:

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * public class ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode next;
 *     ListNode() {}
 *     ListNode(int val) { this.val = val; }
 *     ListNode(int val, ListNode next) { this.val = val; this.next = next; }
 * }
 */
class Solution {
    public ListNode oddEvenList(ListNode head) {
        
    }
}
```

Your code is just fine, it'd pass through:

```
class Solution {
    public ListNode oddEvenList(ListNode head) {
        if (head != null) {
            ListNode odd = head;
            ListNode even = head.next;
            ListNode evenHead = even;

            while (even != null && even.next != null) {
                odd.next = odd.next.next;
                even.next = even.next.next;
                odd = odd.next;
                even = even.next;
            }

            odd.next = evenHead;
        }

        return head;
    }
}
```

If you'd wanted to test locally, for instance, you can create a file called `b.java`:

```
import java.util.*;
import javafx.util.*;

class Solution {
    public ListNode oddEvenList(ListNode head) {
        if (head != null) {
            ListNode odd = head;
            ListNode even = head.next;
            ListNode evenHead = even;

            while (even != null && even.next != null) {
                odd.next = odd.next.next;
                even.next = even.next.next;
                odd = odd.next;
                even = even.next;
            }

            odd.next = evenHead;
        }

        return head;
    }
}


class b {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Solution object = new Solution();
        System.out.println(object);
    }
}


class ListNode {
    int val;
    ListNode next;
    ListNode() {}
    ListNode(int val) { this.val = val; }
    ListNode(int val, ListNode next) { this.val = val; this.next = next; }
}
```

And then write your codes, however you want to test it.